# how can I change wordpress editor Inset link's Class Names?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

Hi how can i add one more class name to wordpress editor insert link style. Any wordpress plugin available for that?

Answer (score 1):

Does one of these help?

- [Adding Custom Link Classes in WordPress](http://www.keighl.com/2010/03/adding-custom-link-classes-in-wordpress/)
- [Insert/edit link Class feature](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/insertedit-link-class-feature)